# Latex Beamer - Toc too long

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm preparing for a master thesis defense... but my presentation is getting a bit lengthy...

...anyways when the ToC gets too long on the side it stretches over. See attached image. Any good advise on how to fix that?

[image: screenshoft_of_the_presentation_notice_the_overlap_on_the_left]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} % Deutsch or English
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %coding utf8
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} %Math symbols
\usepackage{lmodern} % For arbitrary font sizes
\usepackage{pgf} %for logo
\usepackage{etex} %More Registers - against no room for \dimen
\usepackage{graphicx} %for images

\include{physcommand} % my own physics commands
\include{tikz} % Tikz Commands

\usetheme{Berkeley} %general theme
\usecolortheme{default} %color
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %font
\useinnertheme{default} %header, footer, sidebar : circles | default | inmargin | rectangles | rounded
\useoutertheme{default} %slide size and element position:   default | infolines | miniframes |  shadow | sidebar | smoothbars | smoothtree | split | tree
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large} %Make Slide Number large
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] % Show Slide Number
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]} % Fix References Numbers
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % No Navigation in lower right


\title[BCFW For Loop-Level]{BCFW Recursion Relations At Loop-Level} %title
\subtitle[Yang-Mills]{For Yang Mills Theory} %subtitle
\author[H. Hanssen]{Master Thesis Defense} %author
\institute[ T2 -- UHH]{Henrik Hanssen \\[.25cm] II. Institut für Theoretische Physik \\ Universität Hamburg} %Institute
\date[01/10/14]{October 1st 2014} %date
\logo{\pgfimage[width=1cm,height=1cm]{uhh_logo}} %uhh logo
\subject{BCFW for loops}

%\frame[Overlay-Aktionen][Optionen]{Titel}{Untertitel}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}} % Adds Section Title Pages
\AtBeginSubsection{\frame{\subsectionpage}} % Adds Section Title Pages
```

Comment: Use `\section[short title]{long title}` for it -- you did not provide the relevant code for the `\sections` ;-)  Example -- `\subsection[All plus example]{All Plus Amplitude blabla...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lack of a full example file:

It's the same issue as with a non-beamer-document:

`\section{This is a really long section title -- too long for a TOC}` will add exactly

> This is a really long section title -- too long for a TOC

to the TOC. However, any of the structuring commands (`\part`, `\chapter` etc.) has an optional argument designed to hold the short title to appear in the TOC.

`\section[My short title]{This is a really long section title -- to long for a TOC}` will use the

> My short title

in the TOC.

Comment: Doesn't work with beamer. Not sure why this is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues to solve here.

**I. Long Table of Contents**

**a)** There is an answer to this over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913966/how-to-split-table-of-contents-across-multiple-slides-with-latex-beamer)

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
```

which allows overflow to go on to another slide.

**b)** However, I believe the best solution may depend on the theme you are using. In my case the best workaround was

```
\usepackage{multicols}
\begin{mulitcols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
```

which creates two columns and automatically divides the text among the two columns.

**c)** Reconsidering how you organize your table of contents is also a useful alternative. For example you can hide subsections or subsubsections (`subsectionstyle=show/show/hide, subsubsectionstyle=show/show/show/hide` ), and show them later on in your presentation. Having a multi-page table of contents defeats its purpose as a quick overview, so I would suggest this. It's also the least hack-y option, so you will be less likely to run into more errors.

**II. Long Titles**

You can use a shorter name for the section identifier than for the frame title when you arrive on the slide, i.e.

```
\subsection{Brown Fox}
\begin{frame}{The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this old question.