# Short section name in toc

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How to display a short section name in the tabel of contents?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section[short title]{long title}
    \frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200141/36296 this should theoretically work, or am I reading the answer wrong?

Comment: Could you add some more information about what you are trying to do? From this I assume that you want one name for the actual section, but another to show up in the TOC, is this correct?

Comment: yes, I'd like to have the long title when using `\insertsection` but the short form in the TOC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) inserts the ToC and Navigation entries to match the mandatory sectioning command. You'll have to patch each sectional unit separately to "fix" this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Insert [short title] for \section in ToC
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}{{#2}{\the\c@page}}{{#1}{\the\c@page}}{}{}
% Insert [short title] for \section in Navigation
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}{{\the\c@section}{\secname}}{{\the\c@section}{#1}}{}{}
% Insert [short title] for \subsection in ToC
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}{{#2}{\the\c@page}}{{#1}{\the\c@page}}{}{}
% Insert [short title] for \subsection  in Navigation
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}{{\the\c@subsection}{#2}}{{\the\c@subsection}{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[short section]{long section}
\subsection[short subsection]{long subsection}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

`\beamer@section[#1]{#2}` and `\beamer@subsection[#1]{#2}` act very much like the regular `\section[#1]{#2}` and `\subsection[#1]{#2}`, writing `#2` to the `.toc` and `.nav` auxiliary files. The above `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` switches the mandatory one for the optional one when writing to the auxiliaries.

Comment: Do you know what the command is to use the short title in the footer of each slide?

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir: There doesn't seem to be a macro storing that when I looked into [`beamerbasesection.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasesection.sty), so one would have to patch `\beamer@section` and capture argument `#1` for use later.