# beamer: \insertshortsection

Tags: beamer, sectioning

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Sec. A]{Section A}
\subsection{SubSec a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSec b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\section[Sec. B]{Section B}
\subsection{SubSec a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSec b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

- I often use `\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}` (or similar) to automatically generate frame titles in `beamer`.
- Sometimes I would like to use the short version of the title, such as in `\section[Sec. A]{Section A}` --> `\insert`**`short`**`section` (= Sec. A) which is not available (see also [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-beamer/feature-requests/62/)).

**Is there an easy way to access the short version of `section` and friends?** With "easy" I mean that the solution does not have many side effects.

---

### Probably Related

- [Short section name in toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203105)

---

### Solution

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\def\section{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection*{#2}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection*{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection[#1]{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Sec. A]{Section A}
\subsection{SubSec a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection\ \texttt{(long)}: \myshortsec\ \texttt{(short)}: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSec b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection\ \texttt{(long)}: \myshortsec\ \texttt{(short)}: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about a `\nameref` related approach -- this requires labels, however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good idea. That's plan B though :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\insertsectionhead`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Sec. A]{Section A}
\subsection{SubSec a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsectionhead: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer stolen from this one: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578

(It is mine too and have been used at least 5-6 times for solving different problems, but for some reason has still zero votes :( :P )

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\def\section{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection*{#2}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection*{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection[#1]{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\xdef\myshortsec{#1}
\oldsection{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Sec. A]{Section A}
\subsection{SubSec a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sect-\insertsection : short-\myshortsec: \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSec b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sect-\insertsection: short-\myshortsec : \insertsubsection}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

If we redefine sectioning commands this way we can do many things to use their arguments as I noticed in the original answer too :P

Comment: "for some reason has still zero votes" --> not anymore

Comment: I will wait if there are some other solutions if that's ok with you. I am on a business trip and probably be back on Thursday night.

Comment: No problem... You already have a simpler...

Comment: Right - Ulrike's answer is simpler in this case. I will use your code for studying the idea behind. It will help me in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome... (and 5 more to go)

Comment: Could you add some explanation of the basic idea of your solution?

Comment: The idea is to redefine section [used commands 1) `\@ifstar` to check if the section is a starred or a non starred 2) `\ifnextchar` to find out if after the possible star there follows an optional argument 3) 3) Then used the old definition of section after kept (stored) the wanted argument via a `\xdef`]. I could do anything with the arguments in there (capitalize replace words etc).