# Redefining section while keeping short title option

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I am used to redefine the section command (in a beamer document if it matters) as follows:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \oldsection{#1}
  % some code that generates a pretty frame with title section and all
}
```

In doing so, the call to `\oldsection` deals with the non visible stuffs and I only concentrate on the good look I want to give to my frame.

Lately I wanted to use the short title option for my toc, so I decided to adapt that code:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{
  \oldsection[#1]{#2}
  % some code that generates a pretty frame with title section and all
}
```

Surprisingly (for me), it does not work. The toc still uses the full title. What is happening under the hood here? How can I adapt the code to have the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** Where possible you should use the class specific stuff (so the `beamer` code provided by @samcarter in this case). The following answer is just a quick writeup on how one should do such redefinitions to keep all the possibilities of a macro like `\section`.

---

You should use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package for macros taking an optional in general. For the `\section` macro this doesn't seem necessary (at least with the `article` class) as it isn't defined with something like `\newcommand`.

Still you'll have to make sure that you test for an optional star and the optional argument. The optional argument shouldn't be passed on as is, as with the default empty argument you'll only get empty entries in the ToC. The following does the test for a star using the `\@ifstar` macro. It also uses `&` as the default content of the optional argument to test whether it was used at all. One could do this differently using `\@ifnextchar[`, but the approach here is easier to code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section
  {%
    \@ifstar
      {\sectionauxB}
      {\sectionauxA}%
  }
\newcommand\sectionauxA[2][&]
  {%
    \ifx&#1%
      \oldsection{#2}%
    \else
      \oldsection[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\sectionauxB[1]
  {%
    \oldsection*{#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\section[Tes]{Test}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively using `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section
  {%
    \@ifstar
      {\sectionauxD}
      {\sectionauxA}%
  }
\newcommand\sectionauxA
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[
      {\sectionauxB}
      {\sectionauxC}%
  }
\@ifdefinable\sectionauxB
  {%
    \long\def\sectionauxB[#1]#2{\oldsection[#1]{#2}}%
  }
\newcommand\sectionauxC[1]
  {%
    \oldsection{#1}%
  }
\newcommand\sectionauxD[1]
  {%
    \oldsection*{#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\section[Tes]{Test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I would not mess with the section definition in beamer, just use the build in mechanism that let's you automatically insert a section page. If you don't like the default layout of teh section page, you can modify it with `\setbeamertemplate{section page}{some code that generates a pretty frame with title section and all}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \usebeamertemplate{section page}
    \end{frame}
}    

\begin{document}
\section{section name}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I love that image!

Comment: @Skillmon it can be used to answer most beamer questions :)

Comment: @Skillmon However one can learn much more from your answer!

Comment: That's why I've added a disclaimer.

Comment: To be honest, I overlooked the "in a beamer document" part of the question :)

Comment: Thanks ! However it does not fix my problem, I just noticed that even in a plain old beamer documetn without fancy section, the short title option has no effect... (I'm using TeXLive 2015 on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS distribution.)

Comment: @Pece If you want to use the short section name in toc, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203105/short-section-name-in-toc